# NULL POINTER in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, null, memory-address, null-pointer

Why is the address of value NULL pointer different
I have a sample programme below i am trying to understand the concept of NULL pointers. here &q prints different address and 'q' gives 0 what is the reason for this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *q=NULL;

    cout <<"adress of pointer q\n" << q<<endl;
    cout <<"adress with apersand pointer q\n" << &q<<endl;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The NULL pointer is a constant with a value of zero defined in several standard libraries, including iostream.

On most of the operating systems, programs are not permitted to access memory at address 0 because that memory is reserved by the operating system. However, the memory address 0 has special significance; it signals that the pointer is not intended to point to an accessible memory location. But by convention, if a pointer contains the null (zero) value, it is assumed to point to nothing.

References are not pointers.

> A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or
>   function. [Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a
>   well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference
>   would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null
>   pointer, which causes undefined behavior. As described in 9.6, a
>   reference cannot be bound directly to a bit-field. ]

Null pointer certainly does not point to a "valid object or function", and there is no desire within the standards committee to introduce null references.

Comment: what is the reason for &q and q not being same ? if the addres was 0 then why with & i get a memeory address .

Comment: above i explain why nullpointer q print value 0. Address is not zero so &q print memory location.

Comment: @Step `q` is an `int *`, `&q` is an `int **`, they are different types, so it's natural for them to be different values

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized q with NULL, thats why q gives 0.
However, the variable q is stored somewhere, thats the address &q gives.